# Change default font size (style) programmatically

Tags: android

How can I change font size in my app?
For example:
In my app user can choose size of font for whole app.
If he selected one of presented sizes, the font size is changing and the user sees the change in some elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the selected font size by user in a SharedPreference file and set the textsize in every activity's onCreate();
And if u want to show instant change in font size somewhere, set listener for the element.

Comment: How can I set textsize for activity?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you took a selection from the user about the text size and stored in the default SharedPreferences,

```
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String textSize = settings.getString("textSize", "16");
    textview.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(textSize));
```